# Syntax of Closure in PHPDoc

Tags: php, closures, phpdoc

I cant find any documentation on the Closure type in PHPDoc. So my question is how do I define the parameter of the parameters sent to the closure and its return value ?

Example:

How do i describe that the "callback" will get a "MyCustomClass", a Number and a String, and return a "MyOtherCustomClass" ?

```php
/**
 * @param MyCustomClass $cls
 * @param Closure       $callback this isn't really explaining what this is
 *
 * @return MyOtherCustomClass
 */
function changer($cls, $callback){

  return $callback($cls, 2, "a string");
}

changer($aCustomeClass, function($cls, $int, $string){
   return new MyOtherCustomClass($cls, $int, $string);
})
```

Or if its at all possible?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable way to describe it in annotations. Even in PHP manuals they are just referenced as `callable` in descriptions of arguments.

Comment: That is what im fearing but it would be nice if it is possible.

Comment: "In depth Closure definition" discussion: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/830

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`@param callable $callback` is indeed the syntax to use for that part.  You are not limiting that parameter to being a closure itself... any callable that is passed to it will be accepted in that implementation.  Callable is a legal "PHP type", so phpDocumentor accepts it as a valid Type.

In your example code, there's actually *not* a reason to presume that your `changer()` method returns a `MyOtherCustomClass()`, since that is purely dictated by how you write the closure later in the `changer()` usage.  At best, you'd denote in a comment *at* the `changer()` usage that *this particular use of `changer()`* returns `MyOtherCustomClass`, because it is that usage's implementation, not the `changer()` implementation itself, that returns that specific type of object.

As for documenting the arguments that the passed callable is "required" to accept, I suppose you'd have to do that in the description piece of the param tag.  There is no syntax to describe such a case.

If I were to implement something in this manner, I would impose an interface that the callables must all explicitly return, and thus I could write that `changer()` returns that interface.  Of course, this means that your `MyOtherCustomClass` must implement that interface, but still, that seems to me to be the only way of coming close to "enforcing" a return type from `changer()`.

Comment: An interface could solve the problem if I rewote the code. In my case that isn't an option tho.

Comment: Indeed, code rewriting can be a constraint ;-)  I've found that thinking about options that I rule out can still sometimes make other new ideas come up, so I tend to mention such things that come to me while thinking through someone's question.

Comment: givin u the chceck mark ... tho not useable for my current project it is a solution to the problem in general :)

Answer (score 4):

**use indirect technique**

Your code:

```
/**
 * @param MyCustomClass  $cls
 * @param MyFancyClosure $callback
 *
 * @return MyOtherCustomClass
 */
function changer($cls, $callback){
    return $callback($cls, 2, "a string");
}

changer($aCustomeClass, function($cls, $int, $string){
   return new MyOtherCustomClass($cls, $int, $string);
})
```

and than provide a dummy code somewhere:

```
/**
 * this is awesome closure!
 */
class MyFancyClosure {
    /**
     * @param MyCustomClass $cls
     * @param int           $int
     * @param string        $str
     *
     * @return MyOtherCustomClass
     */
    public function __invoke($cls, $int, $str) {}
}
```

note:

1. The function body of __invoke is not required, so leave it blank.
2. Use "Closure" sufix for class name to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out phpstan and psalm support this syntax, and maybe other tools support it too.

```php
/**
 * @param callable(Cls, int, string):MyOtherCustomClass $callback
*/

/**
 * @param Closure(Cls, int, string):MyOtherCustomClass $callback
*/
```

here is the reference for pslam: https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/type_syntax/callable_types/

for phpstan: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#callables