# PHPDoc anonymous function typehinting

Tags: php, anonymous-function, phpdoc

Is there a way in PHPDoc to typehint return value of an anonymous function?

```
/** @var $snail callable */
/** @return Core|string */
$snail = function() { echo "whatever!"; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax of Closure in PHPDoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589902/syntax-of-closure-in-phpdoc)